# Stop OnClick Event from Firing on New Scene Load in Unity for Android Devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, touch

I am experiencing a problem with the UI Button Components in Unity while testing on Android devices. The issue is that the OnClick event is fired when I lift my finger in a new scene if the screen was already being touched before the scene was loaded. Interestingly, this does not happen in the Unity editor on Windows, regardless of whether I am using a mouse or a touchscreen.

Is there a way to stop the OnClick event from firing under these conditions on Android devices? I would like the user to have to press and release the button for the OnClick event to be triggered, rather than just releasing it.

Unity version: 2022.3.7f1

Comment: Have you tried unsubscribing from the button click before switching scenes?

Comment: @hijinxbassist, the buttons don't exist yet before switching scenes, so there is no way to subscribe or unsubscribe.

Comment: Oh wow ok, I thought you meant a button from the previous scene was triggering after the new scene loaded.  From the docs it looks like this shouldn't happen `"Note: Triggered on MouseUp after MouseDown on the same object."`.  Looks like a legit bug in the unity android build.  Im sure there are hacks that can prevent this behaviour, but would likely be messy.  Something like storing a class bool that is true when press down, then checking in the click handler if downPressed is true, otherwise abort.  Not pretty at all.  I suggest filing a bug report with unity.